# I want to install 12.10 Clean but Retain Home from 12.04. Do I need to create separate Home partition?

Tags: installation

I have had major issues with upgrade to 12.10 and have reverted to 12.04. I want to install clean this time around, but would like to retain home.

Do I need to move home to a separate partition first?

I have an encrypted home, do I need to worry about this and make any special accommodations?

Is the [tutorial: UbuntuReinstallation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation) on help.ubuntu.com still relevant for 12.10?

Answer (score 0):

I would extract everything in the encrypted home to somewhere else under /home or /srv and then make a new encrypted home upon installation. Then copy the files back in after reinstalling.

Use the manual partitioning option by selecting 'Something else' at the installation type screen, make sure your root partition is set **not** to format and is mounted to `/` like in the image below. The `Use as:` field should match the type of file system you first installed with, so ext4 by default.

[image]
**Pay no mind to the size field, yours will be different than the ones in my vm.*

Comment: I don't have enough room on my main drive to make a copy of home, so I want to backup to USB unencrypted per your suggestion. What's best method?

Comment: @Kendor I usually just copy the entire home folder with the file manager.

Answer (score 0):

Moving home to a separated partition will be good. Just follow [the community instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving). I’ve tried it before and was successful.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you would have to move it on to a partition. But something like a USB drive. Or a CD.

I only know how to copy and paste on to a OS via CD/USB, not something like a partition. Although I think there is a way to copy and paste via partition.

I would think you would have to change the Home encryption type, but if it lets you, it's lets you.

Thanks.

Comment: Did this work??